# save audio file using MediaStore API

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to create the `URI` but my app crached.this is my code.

```
ContentValues values1 = new ContentValues(1);
        values1.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "My Song.mp3");
        ContentResolver resolver = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
        audiouri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values1);
```

And this is the error that i got.

```
2021-09-20 00:22:22.963 24197-24197/com.example.voicetest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.voicetest, PID: 24197
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.lastIndexOf(int)' on a null object reference
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1956)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1918)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:476)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1587)
    at com.example.voicetest.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:148)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7044)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7017)
    at android.view.View.access$3200(View.java:784)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26596)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6819)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:497)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:912)
```

**UPDATE**

I added this code and it's work fine, but `getContentResolver().insert()` return null

```
   File directory = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);
   values.put(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DATA, "${directory}${song?.title}");
```

Comment: The error is pointing at  `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.lastIndexOf(int)' on a null object reference` . You are providing a null input to lastIndexOf method , which is causing the crash . Make sure you are not providing any null value while getting the lastIndex and the issue will resolve .

Comment: @KaruneshPalekar thanks for the reply. but i can't see anything null??? `startRecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ContentValues values1 = new ContentValues();
                values1.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "My Song.mp3");
                ContentResolver resolver = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
                Uri uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values1);
            }
        });`

Comment: In your entire code , are you extracting certain constant value from a string ? Add the file named DatabaseUtils

Comment: @KaruneshPalekar Thanks for reply,there no Extracting that's all my code.

Comment: Can't tell much from this . Sorry . Because you can clearly see the error says that there is an null pointer exception at when getting an last index of int off string

Comment: Thanks, I'm stack with this for over week

Comment: Did the issue resolve ?

Comment: No, No not yet the problem is I don't know what's the issue. Did u try this code if it's working with u.

Answer (score 0):

```
                File directory = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DATA, "${directory}${song?.title}");
```

I added this code and it's work fine, but `getContentResolver().insert()` return null